# Example CSS for D3 script with R package r2d3?

Tags: css, r, d3.js

I've been looking for a small example setting a style attribute in `css` for `d3` as created by the R package `r2d3`. For the default D3 Script in the beta RStudio, for example,

```
// !preview r2d3 data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20)
//
// r2d3: https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3
//

var barHeight = Math.ceil(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
```

How would I code the equivalent of adding, say,

```
.attr('stroke-width', 2)
.attr('stroke', 'white')
```

to the above, but do so in a css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would style any other CSS attribute. make the selector more specific if needed, most likely add a class to the rect `rect.someclass` .

```
rect {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: white;
}
```